# Embedded YouTube video causes tons of net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I have a site with a couple of embedded YouTube video's like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UfvceH03iAc?origin=https://braintool.org" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my console I get a ton of errors like this:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

from googleads.g.doubleclick.net

I assume the errors are being thrown from inside the iframe and so maybe its out of my control, but I don't like seeing all the red on the console! A quick google doesn't show anything obvious. Any thoughts on how to address?

Thanks

Comment: This is due to ad/privacy/tracker blockers on your browser/platform.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like @randy-casburn was right. I have Ad Block Plus running in Chrome. When I turned it off the errors went away.

Comment: Works in 2024 (I have uBlock Origin)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I will say avoid using the query (?origin=https://braintool.org)